# LWC Public Properties Passed to Children when Asynchronous

Tags: lightning-web-components

Say I have a parent LWC passing a public property to a child LWC:

```
<template>
    <c-todo-wrapper>
        <c-todo-item item-name={itemName}></c-todo-item>
    </c-todowrapper>
<template>
```

if `get itemName()` is asynchronously calculated in the parent, or changes value over time, will the child component be passed the new value(s) and be rerendered each time the value changes?

Or do you just get one shot to pass the value from the parent to the child?

Comment: Yes, it is reactive. Child component is refreshed when public property is changed from parent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if the value changes, those values will be propagated to the children elements. However, when using a getter, something must trigger a rerender (e.g. you must set an attribute on the controller).

Here's an [example](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/TNN81T1CY/2/edit):

```
<template>
    Child:
    <c-child value={theValue}>
    </c-child>
</template>
```

---

```
import { LightningElement, track, api } from 'lwc';

export default class App extends LightningElement {
    value = 0;
    connectedCallback() {
        setInterval(()=>this.value++, 1000);
    }
    get theValue() {
        return this.value*2;
    }
}
```

Comment: To add to this. What happens here is that you change `this.value` inside the interval, so the parent rerenders, therefore the child rerenders since their value will have changed.

In the first release of lwc I think you would have had to annotate value with @track, but a couple of releases ago all properties where made reactive.

Comment: Thanks sfdcfox! Thanks Adrian!